# Turn off spinner from Angular-Calendar-Year-View [https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar-year-view]

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-calendar

I'am using the angular-calendar, and for the Year-View I need, I've implemented:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar-year-view

It works fine, but there is a spinner, I can't turn off. Does anybody now a part of the code, to turn off the spinner?

```
      <angular-calendar-year-view
        *ngSwitchCase="'day'"
        nothingToshowText="An diesem Tag hast du keine ToDo's eingetragen"
        mwlCalendarNextView
        [events]="events"
        [viewDate]="viewDate"
        themecolor="black"
        (eventClicked)="goToEvent($event.event.id)">
      </angular-calendar-year-view>
```

This is how I implemented it. At the moment I just turned the "spinner"-boolean in the dependency to false, but this is crap.

I've also tried something like

```
AngularCalendarYearViewComponent.prototype.spinner = false;
AngularCalendarYearViewComponent.prototype.loader = false;
```

in the typescript file, but it doesn't work, too...

Please help

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export declare class AngularCalendarYearViewComponent implements OnInit {
    sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
    // readonly style: import("@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service").SafeStyle;
    themecolor: any;
    events: any[];
    viewDate: Date;
    nothingToshowText: string;
    popoverEnabled: boolean;
    customTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
    eventClicked: EventEmitter<any>;
    actionClicked: EventEmitter<any>;
    dayClicked: EventEmitter<any>;
    loader: any;
    days: any;
    dayindex: any;
    daydetails: any;
    year: any;
    calendar: any;
    spinner: any;
    constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer);
    ngOnInit(): void;
    ngOnChanges(): void;
    initCalendar(date: any): void;
    generateCalendar(month: any, year: any): any[];
    getNbWeeks(month: any, year: any): number;
    dayClickedFn(day: any, month: any): void;
    getTodayEvents(day: any, month: any): void;
    getnbevents(day: any, month: any): {
        nb: number;
        color: string;
    };
    eventClickedFn(event: any): void;
    refresh(date: any): void;
    actionClickedFn(action: any, event?: any): void;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<AngularCalendarYearViewComponent, never>;
    static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<AngularCalendarYearViewComponent, "angular-calendar-year-view", never, { "themecolor": "themecolor"; "events": "events"; "viewDate": "viewDate"; "nothingToshowText": "nothingToshowText"; "popoverEnabled": "popoverEnabled"; "customTemplate": "customTemplate"; }, { "eventClicked": "eventClicked"; "actionClicked": "actionClicked"; "dayClicked": "dayClicked"; }, never, never>;
}

//# sourceMappingURL=angular-calendar-year-view.component.d.ts.map
```

This is the dependency

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide the spinner.

Something like that worked for me

```
  &:host ::ng-deep .spinner {
    display: none !important;
  }
```